# Autodesk Forge Design Automation quota

Tags: autodesk-forge, autodesk-designautomation

What are the structures/contents of the err messages from Design Automation API when it reaches quota? The main concern is about 'Five requests per minute'. I need to figure out a way to catch/handle err, so the web users won't experience too bad experiences when the app happens to be in a peak moment. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will get 429 status code. Reason-Phrase = Too Many Requests.